# JText language doesnt work inside external ajax file

Tags: joomla-2.5, ajax, language

I'm using an external ajax file to perfom an ajax call inside a module.( i didnt want to edit controller or make a subcontroller just for one call )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).on('click', '.changeBtn',function(){
  var yo="<?php echo 'ip_searchmod_'.$unique_qsid; ?>";
  var text="<?php echo JText:: _('COM_IPROPERTY_THANASIS_ADV_SEARCH');?>";
  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"/templates/spiti360/html/mod_ip_homesearch/ajaxChangeSimple.php",
    success: function(response){

      $('#' + yo).html(response);
      $('#' + yo).addClass('formSwapper');
      $('#top_search_form').addClass('divConSwapper');
      $('#swapper').addClass('simpleBtn');
      $('#swapper').removeClass('changeBtn');
      $('#swapper').text(text);
    }

  });

});
});
```

Ajax is working peftectly , my problem is that im using this `JText:: _('COM_IPROPERTY_THANASIS_FOR_SALE');` inside the ajax file and it is echoed like : `COM_IPROPERTY_THANASIS_FOR_SALE` instead of `For Sale` . 
On the `default.php` file of module that language definition is working perfectly but not inside ajax file.

I tried to use language override from joomla administrator but it didnt work.

Inside ajax file i use the following includes:

```
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
```

Do i have to include anything more for it to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you're `require_once` calls, add the following to initialise the applications:

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Then load the component's language file:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_iproperty', JPATH_ROOT);
```

I have guessed `com_iproperty`, so if it's not correct, please change it.

Comment: No No the JText im using inside jquery is working fine !

The faulty JText is an echo inside the ajax file!

Comment: @IseNgaRt - Is the Ajax file a PHP or JS file?

Comment: It is a PHP file

Comment: Ok, in your Ajax file, please add `<?php var_dump(JPATH_BASE); exit; ?>`. In your console log, this should display a URL or `null`. Please let me know what the result is

Comment: string(36) "/var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs" Its the root folder of the site

Comment: @IseNgaRt - Ok good, Please see my updated answer

Comment: @IseNgaRt - Glad it helped :)