# Language Constants not being replaced in JLayout

Tags: joomla-3.x, jlayout, jtext

I am trying to use Jlayout in a plugin I am writing and everything works fine except that the Language Constants in the layout file are not being replaced.

My call to render the layout is;

```
$layout = new JLayoutFile($layoutname, $layoutpath);
$body = $layout->render($data);
```

In my layout file I have:

```
        <th><?php echo Jtext::_('COM_MEMBERSHIPS_FIELD_MEMBERSHIP_LABEL'); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $displayData['membership']; ?></td>
```

If I dump $body after the render I get:

```
COM_MEMBERSHIPS_FIELD_MEMBERSHIP_LABEL 911
```

The '911' is the data expected for the field membership but I am expecting:

```
Membership: 911
```

I have been chasing this problem for hours now and don't seem to be able to find anything that gives me any clues about what is going on.

What I can share is that the Constant is in the .ini file in both the site and admin language files as the constant is properly replaced in other Views.

My assumption is that for some reason the language files are not found in the Jlayout process, like I am missing a line or something that needs to include it, but I can't find any examples that show anything else is needed.

Comment: As a matter of habit, I write to `.ini` and `.sys.ini`.  Are you doing both?  We don't know if you have any typos elsewhere.  Can you show codes from more of the relevant files?

Comment: Have you found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424445/2943403  Do you wanna check your `getLanguage()`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33674768/2943403

Comment: Someone working on a plugin suggested `$this->loadLanguage('', JPATH_BASE);` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876543/2943403

Comment: This looks relevant: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14157/12352

Comment: @mickmackusa. Thank you for the quick response. I had read the 1st and 3rd link but not the 2nd of which the last answer along with JoomGuy put me onto looking at loading another language file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked a few things since responding. Please see below line break.

Are you calling the `$this->loadLanguage($this->_name, [path/to/language/directory]);` call in your plugin?

At a quick glance, I can see that you appear to have a typo in your `Jtext::_()` call. Try replacing it with `JText::_()` instead.

If this doesn't work:
Have you switched on language debugging?

Will try checking it in plugin I'm working on, and post update accordingly.

---

** UPDATE: **
I can confirm that calling `Jtext::_()` or `JText::_()` result in my `PLG_MYPLUGIN_CONSTANTS` **are** translated.

So, I'd recommend checking that:

1. You have **both** *language files* specified as sub-elements of the **languages** *element* of your extension's manifest file (.xml) with the following values:

```
language/en-GB.plg_system_[your_plugin_name].ini
language/en-GB.plg_system_[your_plugin_name].sys.ini
```

2. You are loading the language using the aforementioned `$this->loadLanguage()` *method* in your plugin's `__construct()` *method*
3. You are successfully translating your plugin's *constants*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I had to add a $this->loadLanguage('com_memberships'); line to the plugin to resolve the issue. With my 20/20 glasses on, and after doing a JFactory::getLanguage, it makes sense because the plugin was called from COM_ACME  but the JLayout was trying to resolve CONSTANTS from COM_MEMBERSHIPS. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoomGuy Your joomla-guy-cardiff.uk site is still "down".  I was hoping to cyberstalk you, but I don't have enough to go on.